# TypeError: HTTPException() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

Error in terminal

```py
raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail=f"posts id {id} not found. " )
TypeError: HTTPException() takes no keyword arguments
```

My controller function is:

```py
@app.get("/post/{id}")
async def get_post(id:int):
  data = get_post_by_id(id)
  
  if not data:
    raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail=f"posts id {id} not found. ")

  return{"data":data}
```

Comment: Where did you import `HTTPException` from? Do you have a minimal, complete example that shows the issue?

Comment: from http.client import HTTPException
from typing import Union
from fastapi import FastAPI,Body,responses,status
from pydantic import BaseModel
from random import randrange

app = FastAPI()

Answer (score 3):

You're importing HTTPException from `http.client` - this is not the `HTTPException` class that FastAPI expects you to raise (or has documented). Instead import FastAPI's `HTTPException` class:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Body,, responses, status
```

Then raise should work as you expect.